# Chapter Roman in tableofcontents

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, roman

I try to change number of chapter to CHAPTER I,II,III in contents and it is done.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill{\small Page}\par}
\AtBeginDocument{% \renewcommand\contentsname{CONTENTS} }

% Centered title for ToC
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}

% Leaders for chapter entries
\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{\cftdotsep}

% Add space to account for new chapter numbering schema
\renewcommand\cftchapnumwidth{8em}
\renewcommand\cftsecindent{3em}

% Redefine representation for chapter (and section) counters
\renewcommand\thechapter{CHAPTER \Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{7}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\section{Background}
\section{Objectives}
\chapter{REVIEW}
\section{Test Section}
\section{AnotherTest Section}
\chapter{CODE}
\chapter{END}

\chapter*{APPENDIX}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{APPENDIX}
\end{document}
```

But for mainmatter, I want to create to have an output like this

[image]

Help me please.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest against renewing `\thechapter` to include the word prefix `CHAPTER`. Instead, add that to `\cftchappresnum`. That is, use something like:

```
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{CHAPTER }
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}
```

Then, to center the chapter heading, you can use [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec):

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\centering}{CHAPTER \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
```

Here is a minimal example that captures everything:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill{\small Page}\par}

\renewcommand\contentsname{CONTENTS}
%\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}

% Centered title for ToC
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill\null}

% Leaders for chapter entries
\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{\cftdotsep}

% Add space to account for new chapter numbering schema
\renewcommand\cftchapnumwidth{8em}
\renewcommand\cftsecindent{3em}

% Redefine representation for chapter (and section) counters
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{CHAPTER }
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\centering}{CHAPTER \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{7}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\section{Background}
\section{Objectives}
\chapter{REVIEW}
\section{Test Section}
\section{AnotherTest Section}
\chapter{CODE}
\chapter{END}

\chapter*{APPENDIX}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{APPENDIX}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}` to get rid of the 'Chapter' in the chapter title.

If you also want to center both lines of the chapter heading, add:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\centering}{\thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
```

Making you MWE look like this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill{\small Page}\par}

\renewcommand\contentsname{CONTENTS}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\centering}{\thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}

% Centered title for ToC
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}

% Leaders for chapter entries
\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{\cftdotsep}

% Add space to account for new chapter numbering schema
\renewcommand\cftchapnumwidth{8em}
\renewcommand\cftsecindent{3em}

% Redefine representation for chapter (and section) counters
\renewcommand\thechapter{CHAPTER \Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{7}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\section{Background}
\section{Objectives}
\chapter{REVIEW}
\section{Test Section}
\section{AnotherTest Section}
\chapter{CODE}
\chapter{END}

\chapter*{APPENDIX}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{APPENDIX}
\end{document}
```

and producing:

[image: output toc]

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't set `renewcommand\chaptername{}`, nor `\renewcommand\thechapter{CHAPTER \Roman{chapter}}` as this may have side-effects, but rather write simply `\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}` and `\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\filcenter}{\chaptername~\thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}`.

Comment: @Bernard am I mistaken or would your suggestion neither achieve capitalization of the 'Chapter' part, nor produce 'CHAPTER I Chapter Title' in the toc? I.e. some of the 'side effects' might be part of the aim here?

Comment: @Bernard also, which side-effects do you envision?

Comment: Well, in cross-references or in theorem numbering: theorem 1 from chapter 3 might be numbered  `Theorem CHAPTER 3.1`. Normally `\thecounter` is only for changing the way the `value` of a counter displays. `CHAPTER` is not exactly part of the chapter number.

Comment: I see it. What should I do?