# Change number after chapter in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, roman

From [Chapter Roman in tableofcontents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196218/chapter-roman-in-tableofcontents) ,
it has an effect on Theorem, Definition etc. I would like to change number of chapter into Roman number in tableofcontents like CHAPTER I in picture.

[image][image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,latexsym}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
%==============THEOREM=================
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{exam}[thm]{Example}
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}
%=================Content=======================
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{CHAPTER}
\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill{\small Page}\par}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Large\bfseries}  
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\chaptername\space} 
\renewcommand\cftchapnumwidth{7em} 
\renewcommand\cftsecindent{4em} 
\renewcommand\cftsecnumwidth{2em} 
\renewcommand\cftsubsecindent{6em}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecnumwidth{3em}
%=============Set Chapter in Page==============
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\centering}{\chaptername\space\Roman{chapter}}{20pt}{\uppercase}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First}
\section{first section}
\section{second section}
\subsection{first}
\begin{thm}
ajsdkla sadjka $a=b$
\end{thm}
\chapter{Second}
\section{first section}
\begin{defn}
asjdk asdk sadjk $a=b$
\end{defn}
\end{document}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define

```
\newcommand*{\Romannumeral}[1]{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral#1}}
```

and change

```
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\chaptername\space}
```

to

```
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\chaptername\space\Romannumeral}
```

Then you may want to increase `\cftchapnumwidth`:

```
\renewcommand\cftchapnumwidth{8em}
```

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,latexsym}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
%==============THEOREM=================
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{exam}[thm]{Example}
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}
%=================Content=======================
\newcommand*{\Romannumeral}[1]{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral#1}}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{CHAPTER}
\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill{\small Page}\par}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\chaptername\space\Romannumeral}
\renewcommand\cftchapnumwidth{8em}
\renewcommand\cftsecindent{4em}
\renewcommand\cftsecnumwidth{2em}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecindent{6em}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecnumwidth{3em}
%=============Set Chapter in Page==============
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\centering}{\chaptername\space\Roman{chapter}}{20pt}{\uppercase}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First}
\section{first section}
\section{second section}
\subsection{first}
\begin{thm}
ajsdkla sadjka $a=b$
\end{thm}
\chapter{Second}
\section{first section}
\begin{defn}
asjdk asdk sadjk $a=b$
\end{defn}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I have one question about appendix. If I put \usepackage[titletoc]{appendix} and \begin{appendices} \chapter{First Appendix}
\end{appendices}, I see Appendix CHAPTER A in contents. Can you help me?

Comment: @Boymath7 Just after `\begin{appendices}` insert `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand\protect\cftchappresnum{}} \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand\protect\cftchapnumwidth{1.5em}}`

Comment: @Boymath7 I would also add `\renewcommand{\appendixname}{APPENDIX}` in the preamble and `\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\centering}{\appendixname\space\Alph{chapter}}{20pt}{\uppercase}` just after `\begin{appendices}`.